# Not able to add launch arguments to google chrome in Windows 10

Tags: powershell, google-chrome, windows-10

I want to add user-data-dir argument to google chrome whenever its launched.
I made following changes for it:

1. Changed registry key `HKCR:\ChromeHTML\shell\open\command` to `"C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe" --user-data-dir=C:\Users\user\testdir --single-argument %1'`
2. Set Argument `--user-data-dir=C:\Users\user\testdir --single-argument %1` to shortcut file `C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Google Chrome.lnk`

However, I see that chrome is running without the new user-data-dir. I don't know using which shortcut chrome was opened.

How can I make this change permanent (preferably using powershell) so that whichever shortcut chrome is opened, it takes the user-data-dir argument?

Comment: Chrome may be interpreting the `\ ` chars. as _escape_ characters; either _double_ them or try using `/` instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not able to find how to make it permanent but able to get the arguments applied by a workaround. Search for all the shortcuts by following command.

```
Get-CimInstance Win32_ShortcutFile | select Name, FileName, CreationDate, LastAccessed, Drive, Path,  FileType
```

Set arguments in the intended shortcuts as given in the second step in the question.